# Nested directives with transclusion

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion

I have a set of form directives in which duplicate code can be extracted into a separate directive.

I know that I can use transclusion, but have not been able to identify any technique that allows this (element cloning or passing functions). Tutorials on pluralsight, sitepoint and few other describe extraction into a directive inside the current directive, but I have not been able to apply them to my use case.

Brief Synopsis:- 
Two sample directives

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label ng-show="visible">Input: 
      <input ng-model="person.name" type="text" required>
    </label>
    <p ng-show="!visible"> {{person.name}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label ng-show="visible">Input: 
      <select> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> ....  </select>
    </label>
    <p ng-show="!visible"> {{person.name}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wish to condense them into directives like

```
<my-input-box ng-model="person.name" required></my-input-box>
<my-select-box options = "person.options"></my-select-box>
```

where my-input-box template is

```
<my-wrapper-box><input ng-model="person.name" type="text" required></my-wrapper-box>
```

and my-select-box template is

```
<my-wrapper-box><select>......</select></my-wrapper-box>
```

Please see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k6LWjn?p=preview

How do I extract the wrapper box so that 2-way binding is maintained with the ng-model and overriding attributes like required, bootstrap classes, validation regex, etc. in either the my-wrapper-box or the transcluded HTML element?

Many thanks to all who have read the question. I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/owUf9MqRSbFa7tkiTBc5?p=preview).

I've added the following to `myInputBox` directive:

```
controller: function(){},
bindToController: true,
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
```

and changed the html to

```
<my-wrapper-box>
  <input type="text" ng-required="reqd"  ng-model="ctrl.value" />
</my-wrapper-box>
```

Comment: Thanks @tpsilva,
Although, I have not yet understood the bindToController and controllerAs properties, your fix does solve my problem. 
Thanks a lot.